# How to add incremental row number in a data flow task in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-component

I current want to add a new column that allow me to add row number within a data flow task in SSIS (row number increments with each new row).

So far I have been using the following code from this guide:
I currently am using Visual Studio 2015.

- [HOW TO ADD A ROWNUMBER TO A DATA FLOW TASK IN SSIS 2012](https://hansmichielscom.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/)

However, once I run the script I am getting the current error. Seems like it's saying there's a bug in the script, although I can't find this. Also note that I am very new to writing scripts, so I am having some difficulties with this.

> Error at Grab landing data and populate staging [Script Component [88]]: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
>
> Error at Grab landing data and populate staging [Script Component [88]]: The script component includes no code. Edit the component to include code.
>
> Error at Grab landing data and populate staging [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Script Component" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> Error at Grab landing data and populate staging [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Grab landing data and populate staging: There were errors during task validation.

Any suggestions will help, thanks!

Comment: This is often achieved by using an IDENTITY column in the target database. But anyway... first confirm whether the code actually builds. There's a build button.... somewhere in the editor. If you google "The binary code for the script is not found" you'll get a million hits - why don't you try some of those

Comment: @Yola Z, follow this article instead http://www.sqlis.com/post/Row-Number-Transformation.aspx which requires no coding

Comment: @yola what is the sql server version you are working with?? visual studio version??

Comment: @Arthur I've been getting an error message using that link. I'd be interested in the contents of that link, do you know of another means to access it?

Comment: Can't edit my comment, but yes, the link is now defunct @Yola Z Use instead https://www.hansmichiels.com/2015/11/13/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/ please or I even found a nice components that requires 0 coding: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-ssis-component-rownumber.html

Answer (score 1):

## Trying to figure out the issue

I think that there are two possibles causes for this error:

### (1) TargetServerVersion

Check that the `TargetServerVersion` select is the appropriate installed SQL Server version:

In the solution explorer, Right click on the SSIS Project Node and click **Properties**.
When you see Properties select **Configuration Properties**. You will see **TargetServerVersion** change that to the relevant SQL Server version then Click OK.

[image]

*Reference: [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)*

### (2) Script code errors

After searching for this issue, i found many suggestion on the web. To summarize them:

- Try to clean and rebuild the script project within the script editor
- Set `Delay Validation` to true if you are using SSIS 2008 and later versions
- Set "PrecompileScriptIntoBinaryCode" to true if you are using SSIS 2005

You can find more details at:

- [13.The binary code for the script is not found-SSIS](http://ssiserror.blogspot.com/2016/06/13the-binary-code-for-script-is-not.html)
- [SSIS Error: The binary code for the script is not found](https://coderwall.com/p/dfcrkq/ssis-error-the-binary-code-for-the-script-is-not-found)
- [SSIS Binary Code is not found - You need to investigate by yourself](http://sqlcodespace.blogspot.com/2015/02/ssis-binary-code-is-not-found-you-need.html)